# PHP script exits with no errors when calling decrypt_string()

Tags: php, apache, openssl

The following script halts at the `openssl_decrypt()` call.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo 'extension_loaded: ' . extension_loaded('openssl') . '<br>';
echo 'decrypted string: ' . openssl_decrypt("eXIp3BnsELdTuTvVkpoFqXuYoP6zd73ETDXiNcMhXUiuAm0ju4ufdX9Yxai4X7S3", "AES-128-ECB", "some password") . '<br>';
echo 'end<br>';
?>
```

Returns:

```
extension_loaded: 1
```

The script output says that the module is loaded and phpinfo() returns this:

```
openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Version     OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips 26 Jan 2017
```

Comment: It works for me. Also, for the love of god don't use ECB.

Comment: This tuns fine on my local dev machine, so I'm guessing it might be an issue with your environment. Assuming you're using apache2, what do the logs say? Have you modified php.ini? Have you tried using `exec` with the OpenSSL cli tool? Are you running off of windows or a linux distro?

Comment: This is a hosting service. I don't think I can access these things. It works on a default XAMPP Windows installation as well. I'm wondering if FIPS has anything to do with this, or if it's just a faulty server.

Comment: Hmm, well besides checking your control panel to see if you have access to any of these features, I would contact your host.